# Prove that $a \leq 0$ if $a \leq \frac 1 n$ for all $n$

Tags: analysis

The full question reads:
Suppose that $a$ is a number that has the property that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a \leq 1/n$. Prove $a \leq 0$.

Is there anyway to show this using Archimedean Property, or is it something related to the Completeness Axiom?  The problem using the Archimedean Property is that I get up to $a< \epsilon$ but from there I am not able to conclude anything about whether $a \leq 0$ because $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: HINT: [Archimedean property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property).

Comment: For any $\varepsilon>0$ exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $0<\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$

Comment: People are really coming out of the woodwork to answer this!

Comment: It is nice that $\mathbb{R}$ is first-countable, isn't it? :)

Comment: "Anyway" is a perfectly respectable word, but it should not be used as a synonym of "any way" (two words).  But in the last few years I've seen a number of cases of people doing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In other words, prove that $a\not>0$. Assume $a>0$, what does that tell you about some $n$?

Answer (score 3):

I'll not give the complete answer to this (on purpose).

But here is some intuition:  if you have a positive number, what can you say about that positive number as compared to the numbers $1/n$ for each n?

Start with something concrete, like 0.1 for example.  It can't have the property you mention... why not?

The same reason works for all positive numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If $a \leq 1/n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $a \le \inf \{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}=0$. Now, to prove that the inf is $0$, you need the Archimedean Property. (The inf being 0 is actually *equivalent* to the Archimedean Property.)

Comment: Note also that this uses the Completeness Axiom. In fact, the Completeness Axiom implies the Archimedean Property.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $a>0$. Then by the Archimedean Property, there exists a natural number $n$ so that $1/n<a$. But this is a contradiction. Then $a\leq0$ if $a\leq 1/n$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a>0$,then there exists some $\epsilon$ such that $0<\epsilon<a$.

Let $N=[\epsilon]+1$,then $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon<a$, which contradicts to that for every $n∈N, a≤1/n$.

So, $a\leq0$.[Q.E.D]

Above is implied in @Daniel's and @lhf's answers.

Answer (score -1):

$n$ is a natural number, therefore it can be $1,2,3, \ldots$. On the other hand, $1/n$ is a continuous function for every real $x$ distinct to zero.

Applying the following limit
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } a \le \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{n} = 0
$$

$$
a \le 0
$$

$$Q.E.D.$$

Comment: $1/n$ is not continuous.

Comment: Whatever that means.

Comment: it is continuous for every x distinct to zero, as stated above.

Comment: The problem states $n \in \mathbb{N}$.